# GSON Convert Array of Different type

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gson

Consider the following `JSON`:

```
{"test":[["abc",12],["fgs",23],...]}
```

How can I map it to java object using `GSON` or spring `RestTemplate`?

I can't use `List<>` since it is of different type.

I tried `Hashmap`, `Map` all throws exception.

```
public class Json implements Serializable{
  @Getter @Setter List<Map<String,Integer>> test;
}
...
Json json = new GSON().fromJson(response.getBody(),Json.class);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ suggests `List<List<String>>`. `List<List<Object>>` is also an option.

Comment: Your example input is a `Map<String,List<?>>` in Java.

Comment: Yeah, I end up using `List<List<String>>` after struggling whole day for searching the right method